# I am trying to show $\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to show $\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$

It was an exercise from a book about complex analysis, so I've gone through the complex plane to do it!

Consider a semi-circle where |z|=R and $0<\arg(z)<\pi$.

consider another, the exact same definition but swap R for $\epsilon$, I want to integrate from -R to $-\epsilon$ over the semi-circle that starts at $-\epsilon$ to $\epsilon$ then along the straight line to R, then from R anti-clockwise back to -R.

I've been given the hint that the integral in the anticlockwise direction is zero, but the clockwise direction (for the $\epsilon$) is -j$\pi$

Here's the problem, my function is: $f(z)=\frac{e^{jz}}{z}$

I've established that f(z)dz = $je^{jz}$ but no amount of playing around has made this expression tolerable.

Because I am considering the integral from 0 to infinity, if I can bound it above somehow by zero I can "sandwich" it between 0 and something that tends to zero.

So far no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Since the integrand is even function, then you can consider

$$ \int^\infty_0\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx .$$

Comment: I gave this an upvote since I used it to finish the problem :) sorry. However, I did leave the OP with some things to think about.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

1. \begin{align}\color{#0000ff}{\large%
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x}
   &=
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\pars{\half\int_{-1}^{1}\expo{\ic k x}\,\dd k}\,\dd x
   \\[5mm] & =
   \pi\int_{-1}^{1}\pars{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic k x}\,{\dd x \over 2\pi}}
   \,\dd k
   =
   \pi\int_{-1}^{1}\delta\pars{k} = \color{#0000ff}{\Large\pi}
   \end{align}
2. \begin{align}
   0& =\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}{\expo{\ic x} \over x}\,\dd x
   +
   \int_{\pi}^{0}{\expo{\ic\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}} \over \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}\,
   \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta 
   +
   \int_{\epsilon}^{R}{\expo{\ic x} \over x}\,\dd x
   +
   \int_{0}^{\pi}{\expo{\ic R\expo{\ic\theta}} \over R\expo{\ic\theta}}\,
   R\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta 
   \end{align}
   With the limit $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$:
   \begin{align}
   0& =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\pars{\int_{-R}^{-\epsilon}{\expo{\ic x} \over x}\,\dd x
   +
   \int_{-\epsilon}^{-R}{\expo{-\ic x} \over x}\,\dd x}
   -
   \ic\pi
   \\[2mm] & + \ic\int_{0}^{\pi}\expo{\ic R\expo{\ic\theta}}\,\dd\theta 
   \\[3mm]&=
   -2\ic\int_{0}^{R}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x -\ic\pi
   +
   \ic\int_{0}^{\pi}\expo{\ic R\expo{\ic\theta}}\,\dd\theta
   \\[5mm]
   \color{#0000ff}{\large%
   \int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x} &=
   \color{#0000ff}{\large{\pi \over 2}}
   +
   {1 \over 2}\overbrace{\lim_{R \to \infty}
   \int_{0}^{\pi}\expo{\ic R\cos\pars{\theta}}\expo{-R\sin\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta}
   ^{\ds{=\ 0}}
   \end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Though this is not what you asked for originally, let me offer a a very elegant real variable approach, for a change. I actually wrote an extensive [blog post](http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/175-the-sine-integral/) on this, with a few nice graphs, a while ago, so here I'll just give you the bare bones sketch. The argument comes from **Introduction to Calculus and Analysis, vol. I**, by Richard Courant and Fritz John, Interscience Publishers (1965), reprinted by  Springer (1989).

Note first that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}x\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$, where $\displaystyle a_k=\int_{\pi k}^{\pi(k+1)}\frac{\sin x}x\,dx=\int_0^\pi\frac{(-1)^k\sin t}{\pi k +t}\,dt$. This shows that the integral converges, by Leibniz criterion.

Second, note that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}x\,dx=\lim_{\rho\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi\rho}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\lim_{\rho\to\infty}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(\rho t)}{t}\,dt$.

Third, and this is the key, $\displaystyle \lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^\pi\sin\left(\left(k+\frac12\right)t\right)\left(\frac1t-\frac1{2\sin(t/2)}\right)\,dt=0$. To see this, let $\displaystyle f(t)=\frac1t-\frac1{2\sin(t/2)}$. Check that $\lim_{t\to0^+}f(t)=0$ and, defining $f(0)=0$, we have that $f'(0)$ exists and equals $-1/24=\lim_{t\to0^+}f'(t)$. It follows that $f$ is continuously differentiable on $[0,\pi]$ so we can integrate by parts to get 
 $$  \int_0^\pi\sin((k+1/2)t)f(t)\,dt=\frac1{k+1/2}\int_0^\pi\cos((k+1/2)t)f'(t)\,dt\to_{k\to\infty}0. $$

It follows that $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}x\,dx=\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(k+\frac12)x}{2\sin(x/2)}\,dx$.

Fourth, recall the identity $\displaystyle f_k(t)=\frac{\sin(k+\frac12)t}{2\sin(t/2)}$, where  $$ f_k(t)=\frac12+\cos t+\cos(2t)+\dots+\cos(kt). $$ It follows that $\displaystyle \int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(k+\frac12)t}{2\sin(t/2)}\,dt=\int_0^\pi f_k(t)\,dt= \frac{\pi}2$, and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

Lastly using the hint above, we finish by saying, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^iz}{z-0}dz=Im(2i\pi(Res_{z=0}f(z)))=Im(2i\pi(e^{iz}|_{z=0})) = Im(2i\pi*1)= 2\pi \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^iz}{z-0}dz=\pi$

We want imaginary since we are  looking at $\sin$. I skipped some detail but I leave it to you to fill in the rest. :)

Specifically: Jordan's lemma to deduce $\int_{c_R}\frac{e^{iz}}{z} dz = 0$