# Is the series $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\int_{i\pi}^{(i+1)\pi} \frac{\sin x}{x}$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm wondering if the series
$$ \sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\int_{i\pi}^{(i+1)\pi} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}  \ \ \ \ \ i\in \mathbb N$$
is convergent or not.

This is my attempt:

I consider the partial sum of it as a sequence, so I let $$I_n=\sum^{n-1}_{i=1}\int_{i\pi}^{(i+1)\pi} \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$$

By the property of integration, this is equal to $$ I_n= \int_{\pi}^{n\pi} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \ dx $$

Then, by using integration by parts, I can get
$$ I_n=\int_{\pi}^{n\pi} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \ dx=x^{-1} \cos x\bigg|_{n\pi}^\pi -\int ^{n\pi}_{\pi}\dfrac{\cos x}{x^2} \ dx$$

Thus the series is $$ \lim_{n\to \infty } \int_{\pi}^{n\pi} \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \ dx=\lim_{n\to \infty } x^{-1} \cos x\bigg|_{n\pi}^\pi -\int ^{n\pi}_{\pi}\dfrac{\cos x}{x^2} \ dx$$

Then, the first term is zero, the second term is an improper integration. And since $\left|\dfrac{\cos x}{x^2}\right| \le \dfrac{1}{x^2}$, the second term is convergent.

Thus the series is convergent.

Is this proof right? I strongly doubt my proof. Could you please check this? Thank you very much!

Comment: You may search Dirichlet integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$.
It is well-known that the integral exists in improper sense: $\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$
exists and can be computed using residue theory in complex analysis.
However, $\int_{0}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|dx=+\infty$.

Comment: The first piece of your integration by parts is not correct but you can easily fix it.

Comment: @Anne Bauval. Yeah, you are right, I fixed it. Are there any other problems with this proof? Thanks

Comment: @Danny Pak-Keung Chan. I see. I think that means my conclusion that this series is convergent is right but is my proof okay?

Comment: @amWhy, in titles is it possible to use $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$? [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/771461) seems that it is accepted. Please, read it and tell me if you agree.

Comment: @Angelo Why wouldn't it be possible to use $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ in the title? It is supported in inline MathJax.

Comment: @FShrike, $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ looks ugly, so if it is possible I would prefer to use $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$, moreover, if you click on the link in my previous comment, it seems that it is accepted by this community.

Comment: This type of question has been discussed in MSE many times. Here is on instance [I am trying to show $\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589158/i-am-trying-to-show-int-infty-0-frac-sinxxdx-frac-pi2)