# calculate $ \lim \limits_{x \to 0} x^a \int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^{a+1}} \, dt$

Tags: integration, limits

Let $ f$ be a continious function and $a>0$

calculate the limit 
$$ \lim \limits_{x \to 0} x^a \int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^{a+1}} \, dt$$

i tried to divied to 2 cases, if $ \lim \limits_{x \to 0}  \int_x^1 \frac{f(t)}{t^{a+1}} \, dt = L < \infty$

then the answer is clearly $0$, else we can use l'Hopital rule, but I'm not sure how to apply it on the integral,

I know that if $F(x) = \int_0^x \frac{f(t)}{t^{a+1}} \, dt$
then the derivative will be $\frac{f(x)}{x^{a+1}} $
but what do i do with $\int_x^1$

thx

Comment: If $F(x) = \int_x^1 f(t)/t^{a+1}\, dt$, then $F'(x) = -f(x)/x^{a+1}$.

Comment: can you please explain why?

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus, and also $F(x) = -\int_1^x f(t)/t^{a+1}\, dt$.

Comment: so if $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt$ then $F'(x) = f(t)$ for every a? not only for a=0?

Comment: Yes, as long as $f$ is continuous on $[a,x]$.

Answer (score 0):

1. This integral limit already has had attention [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107675/correct-way-to-prove-the-limit-mathop-lim-limits-x-to-0-x-alpha-in?rq=1)
2. A series expansion based upon integration by parts is provided in this solution.

Let
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{x}^{1} \frac{f(t)}{t^{a+1}} \, dt \\
&= \left[ - \frac{1}{a} \, t^{-a} \, f(t) \right]_{x}^{1} + \frac{1}{a} \, \int_{x}^{1} \frac{f'(t)}{t^{a}} \, dt \\
&= \left[ - \frac{1}{a} \, t^{-a} \, f(t) \right]_{x}^{1} + \left[ - \frac{1}{a \, (a-1)} \, t^{-a+1} \, f'(t) \right]_{x}^{1} + 
\frac{1}{a \, (a-1)} \, \int_{x}^{1} \frac{f''(t)}{t^{a-1}} \, dt \\
&= \left[ \frac{f(x)}{a \, x^{a}} + \frac{f'(x)}{a(a-1) \, x^{a-1}} + \cdots \right] - \left[\frac{f(1)}{a} + \frac{f'(1)}{a(a-1)} + \cdots \right] + \cdots + \frac{1}{a!} \, \int_{x}^{1} \frac{f^{(a)}(t)}{t} \, dt 
\end{align}

Now, taking the desired limit yields
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \, x^{a} \, \int_{x}^{1} \frac{f(t)}{t^{a+1}} \, dt = \frac{f(0)}{a}
\end{align}
It is required that$a \neq 0$.

Comment: However, we only know that $f$ is continuous, not $C^\infty$.