# How to prove that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is not Lebesgue integrable on $[0,+\infty]$?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

How to prove that $\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}\left|\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\right| \, dx = +\infty$ ?
Could any one give some hint ? Thanks.

Comment: This has been answered [before](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/104678).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|dx\geq\frac{1}{(k+1)\pi}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}|\sin x|dx.$$

You can bound the integral below by a constant multiple of the harmonic series.

Comment: A nice solution, thx!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\sum \frac {1}{n} =$ is unbounded. Consider the intervals where $|\sin x| > \frac {1}{2}$.