# Prove that the series is non-absolutely convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$a_n = \int_{(2n-2)\pi}^{(2n-1)\pi} \dfrac{\sin t}{t} dt$$

The series is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$$

I tried using the Cauchy criterion, and this let me with the next inequality:

$$\left| S_m - S_n \right| \le \left|\int_{(2(n+1)-2)\pi}^{(2(n+1)-1)\pi}
\dfrac{\sin t}{t}dt\right|
+ \cdots +\left|\int_{(2m-2)\pi}^{(2m-1)\pi}\dfrac{\sin t}{t}dt\right| \le \int_{2n\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi}\dfrac{1}{t}dt+\cdots+\int_{(2m-2)\pi}^{(2m-1)\pi}\frac 1t dt$$

But I don't know if I need evaluete the integrals or make another inequality with them and then integrate.

Comment: [Possible doublicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67198/does-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxdx-have-an-improper-riemann-integral-or).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin{t}\geqslant{0}$ on $[(2n-2)\pi,\ (2n-1)\pi]$   and $\sin{t}\geqslant\dfrac{1}{2}$ for $t\in \left[(2n-2)\pi+\frac{\pi}{6},\; (2n-1)\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}\right]$
$$a_n = \int\limits_{(2n-2)\pi}^{(2n-1)\pi} \dfrac{\sin t}{t} dt \geqslant \int\limits_{(2n-2)\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}}^{(2n-1)\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}} \dfrac{\sin t}{t} dt \geqslant \dfrac{1}{2}\int\limits_{(2n-2)\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}}^{(2n-1)\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}} \dfrac{dt}{t} =\\
=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln{\dfrac{(2n-1)\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}}{(2n-2)\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln{\dfrac{12n-7}{12n-11}}=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln\left(1+\dfrac{4}{12n-11} \right)\underset{n\to\infty}\sim\dfrac{2}{12n-11}>\dfrac{1}{6n}$$

Comment: There's no need to integrate (not that it's hard). $\int_a^b \frac{dt}{t} > \int_a^b \frac{dt}{b}= \frac{b-a}{b}$, which with the values of $a$ and $b$ you have will take care of things.

Comment: But, the last limit goes to 0?

Comment: Since the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}}$ diverges and ${a_n} > \frac{1}{6}\cdot{\frac{1}{n}}$ then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ is divergent by [comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test).

Comment: Of course. But the step between the log and $\dfrac{2}{12n-11}$ is not clear for me.

Comment: I used the equivalence $\ln(1+x)\underset{x\to{0}}\sim{x}$ with $x=\dfrac{4}{12n-11}.$

Comment: Were I can find more info about that @M.Strochyk?

Comment: The equivalence $\ln(1+x)\underset{x\to{0}}\sim{x}$ is another form of $\lim\limits_{x\to{0}}{\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}}=1,$ which can be found in every calculus textbook.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a big hint.

$$|a_n| = \int_{(2n-2)\pi}^{(2n-1)\pi}\frac{|\sin t|}{t}\,dt > \int_{(2n-\frac{11}{6})\pi}^{(2n-\frac{7}{6})\pi}\frac{|\sin t|}{t}\,dt> \int_{(2n-\frac{11}{6})\pi}^{(2n-\frac{7}{6})\pi}\frac{1/2}{t}\,dt{\textrm.}$$