# Example for continuous $f$ such that $\int \limits_{0}^\infty |f(x)|dx < \infty$ and $\int \limits_{0}^\infty f^2(x)dx=\infty$.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Does $f = \dfrac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}$ make it?

I know that $\int \limits_{0}^\infty \dfrac{\sin^2(x)}{x}dx = \infty$, but does $\int \limits_{0}^\infty \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{|x|}dx < \infty$?

What would be a good example?

Comment: If I recall correctly, $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ does not converge absolutely, take a look here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1314920/how-does-one-show-that-int-0-infty-left-frac-sin-x-x-right-dx-infty?noredirect=1

Comment: something like $\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: From [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "Your question should be clear without the title. 
After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int \limits_{0}^\infty \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{|x|}dx = \infty$

and

$\int \limits_{0}^\infty \dfrac{|\sin(x)|}{\sqrt x}dx = \infty$
(which is more relevant here).

$f(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt x}$ for $0<x<1$, $f(x)=2-x$ for $1\leq x <2$ and  and $f(x)=0$ for  $x\geq 2$ gives such a    function.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention continuity. Edited

Comment: @YoavShkedy I have modified my $f$ to make it continuous.

Comment: This function is not defined at $0$, and it can't be extended in a continuous way

Comment: @jjagmath It's continuous on $(0,+\infty)$. Nowhere in the question is it mentioned that $f$ must also be continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}n(1-n^3|x-n|) &\mathrm{if}\,|x-n|<\frac1{n^3}\\0& \mathrm{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

That is, $f_n$ is continuous, has a triangular peak at $x$ of height $n$, and is $0$ outside of $[x-\frac{1}{n^3},x-\frac{1}{n^3}]$.

You can compute $\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{1}{n^2}$ and $\int_0^\infty (f_n(x))^2\,\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{2}{3n}$.

Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty f_n(x)$. Then $f$ is continuous on $[0,+\infty)$, $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ is bounded, while $\int_0^\infty (f(x))^2\,\mathrm{d}x$ is not.

Here is a plot of $f$ on $[0,10]$:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following fact.

Let
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{|x|^{a}}  & |x|\leq1, \\
0 & \text{else}.
\end{cases}$$Then $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ $\iff$ $a<n.$