# Find the Principal Value of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x \sin(x)}{x^2+2x+2}\,dx$

Tags: improper-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

This problem comes from a preliminary exam from 2009

Find the Principal Value of the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x \sin(x)}{x^2+2x+2}\,dx$$

My attempt at solution: Letting $f(z)=\frac{z \sin(z)}{z^2+2z+2}$,  the residue theorem implies that $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx=2\pi i \text{Res}(f, -1+i)$, but I get that Res$(f, -1+i)=(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2})\sin(-1+i)$, and I don't know how to compute $\sin(-1+i)$.

Also, I was hoping someone could help me to understand why the problem asks for the "Principal Value" rather than the value because the only singularities of the function $f(z)=\frac{z \sin(z)}{z^2+2z+2}$ are at $-1\pm i$, neither of which are on the real axis.

Comment: $\sin(-1+i)=\sin(1)\cos(i)-\sin(i)\cos(1)$, $\sin(i)=i\sinh(1)$ and $\cos(i)=\cosh(1)$, so $\sin(i-1)=\sin(1)\cosh(1)-i\sinh(1)\cos(1).$ It's not pretty, but there it is.

Comment: @AlexS Thanks! Although I think you computed $-\sin(-1+i)$.

Comment: Because the integral is not absolutely convergent, it exists as an improper Riemann integral but not as a (proper) Lebesgue integral — see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67198/does-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxdx-have-an-improper-riemann-integral-or) for further discussion. Probably that's why the principal value is asked for...

Comment: @user140776 With respect to the Cauchy PV, this is due to the limits at $\pm \infty$.  Second, to use contour integration, we use a trick in which we write $\sin x=\text{Im}(e^{ix})$, carry out the integration in the complex plane and take imaginary part at the end.  Please let me know how I can improve my posted answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the integral of interest can be written

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+2x+1}dx=\text{Im}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+2x+1}dx\right) \tag 1$$

Let's examine the integral

$$\oint_C\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+2z+1}dz$$

where $C$ is the closed contour comprised of

$(i)$ the real-line segment from $(-R,0)$ to $(R,0)$

$(ii)$ the semicircle $C_R$ in the upper-half plane, centered at the origin with radius $R$.

Thus, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+2z+1}dz&=\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{xe^{ix}}{x^2+2x+1}dx+
\int_{C_R}\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+2z+1}dz \tag 2\\\\
\end{align}$$

Note that in the limit as $R\to \infty$, the imaginary part of first integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ equals the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of the integral of interest in $(1)$.  The second integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ can be shown using [Jordan's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) to go to zero in the limit as $R\to \infty$.  Thus, from the residue theorem we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+2x+1}dx=\text{Im}\left(2\pi i \,\text{Res}\left(\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+2z+2},z=-1+i\right)\right)\tag 3$$

The residue in $(3)$ can be evaluated as

$$\begin{align}
\text{Res}\left(\frac{ze^{iz}}{z^2+2z+2},z=-1+i\right)&=
\lim_{z\to -1+i}\frac{(z+1-i)ze^{iz}}{(z+1-i)(z+1+i)}\\\\
&= \frac{(-1+i)e^{i(-1+i)}}{2i} \\\\
&=\frac{e^{-1}}{2i}\sqrt{2}e^{i(3\pi/4-1)}\tag 4
\end{align}$$

Substituting $(4)$ into $(3)$ reveals that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin x}{x^2+2x+1}dx=\pi e^{-1}(\cos 1 -\sin 1)}$$

Comment: Does the integral converges absolutely? I am trying to figure it out........

Comment: @Perpendicular It does not converge absolutely.

Comment: thank you.I used the limit comparison test using for comparison the function $\frac{sin(ax)}{x}$