# Compute $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$ without residue theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Is there a way to compute $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx$$ without residue theorem ?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67198/does-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxdx-have-an-improper-riemann-integral-or)

Comment: you can also use Fourier transform on $f(x)=\chi_{[-1/2,1/2]}$.

Comment: use parity and then differentiate $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}$. Afterwards make use of the fact that the FT of $1$ is a $\delta$-distribution