# How to prove using the Abel test that $\int_ {1}^\infty \frac{|\sin x|}{x}$ is divergent?

Tags: real-analysis

> How to prove using the Abel test that $\int_ {1}^\infty    \frac{|\sin x|}{x}$ is divergent?

Comment: The limit of $x^1\times f(x),~~x\to\infty$ is not zero so it diverges.

Comment: Write the integral as a sum of integrals over intervals for which the sine function is of $1$ sign only.  Then, apply thW MVT for integrals and compare wih the harmonic series.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/67198/9464

Comment: The Abel's test is a test for *convergence* of infinite series. I don't understand why you put that in the question while what you want is showing the improper integral being divergent.

Comment: @BabakS. There are functions $f\ge 0$ such that $xf(x) \not \to 0$ and yet $\int_1^\infty f < \infty.$

Comment: @zhw.: See this [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwik85CjjZnRAhVECBoKHV8kBNAQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fasrichiquita.staff.gunadarma.ac.id%2FDownloads%2Ffiles%2F44928%2FWrede%2Bdan%2BMurray%2B-%2BAdvanced%2BCalculus%2B-%2B3rd%2BEdition.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGgPIjvi5JdTb8n9LF63u1tNYqNCQ&sig2=YvBbJJEjfzKh0BkzcxGQnA&bvm=bv.142059868,d.bGg), page 324 Theorem 1

Comment: @BabakS. Why did you want me look at that? It has nothing to do with my comment.

Answer (score 1):

For $n>0$, we have

$$\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx=$$

$$\int_0^{\pi}\frac{|\sin(t)|}{t+n\pi}\geq \frac{2}{(n+1)\pi}.$$
since $\int_0^{\pi}\sin(t)dt=2$.

Thus,

$$\int_{\pi}^{(n+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{x}dx$$

$$\geq \frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(k+1)}$$ 
which goes to $+\infty$ when $n$ tends to $+\infty$ as an harmonic series. The integral is therefore divergent.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&\int_1^M \frac{|\sin x|}xdx>\int_1^M \frac{\sin^2 x}xdx=I(M)\\
\\
I(M)&=\int_{1+\pi/2}^{M+\pi/2} \frac{\sin^2 (x-\pi/2)}{x-\pi/2}dx=\int_{1+\pi/2}^{M+\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2 x}{x-\pi/2}dx\\
&>\int_{1+\pi/2}^{M+\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2 x}{x}dx\\
&=\int_{1}^M \frac{\cos^2 x}{x}dx-\int_{1}^{1+\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2 x}{x}dx+\int_M^{M+\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2 x}{x}dx\\
&>\int_{1}^M \frac{\cos^2 x}{x}dx-\int_{1}^{1+\pi/2} \frac{\cos^2x}{x}dx\\
&=\int_{1}^M \frac{\cos^2 x}{x}dx+K\\
\\
2I(M)&>\int_1^M \frac{\sin^2 x}xdx+\int_1^M \frac{\cos^2 x}xdx+K\\
&=\int_1^M \frac1xdx+K=\ln M+K\\
\end{align}
which means $\lim_{M\to\infty} I(M)$ diverges and so does the original integral.

Comment: Manipulating formally a set of divergent integrals lacks rigor.  Start with a bounded upper limit and proceed in an analogous fashion.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV Hi Dr., thanks for your advice. Do you mean it would be better if I assumed that the integral converges and hence had some upper bound and then it leads to some condtradict..?

Comment: If the upper limit is finite, then the integrals exist.  Then, the same formal manipulations you used are valid.  Wait until the end to take the limit as the upper limit approaches infinity

Comment: @Dr.MV I got it. Thanks. I also revised the above answer accordingly.

Comment: You forgot to transform the upper limit upon substitution.

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: You should consider showing that $K(M)$ is bounded as $M\to \infty$.

Comment: @Dr.MV The portion of the $K(M)$ that's a function of $M$ is just greater than zero, so I revised so that $K$ is a constant. Please let me know if it's okay now. Thanks!