# Convergence of $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I'm working on proving the convergence of the below integral, the value of which I know to be $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{2}$.
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx
$$
I'm also well aware that this question has been answer several times on this site. Yet, I'm writing this as a question because I've tried the below method which looks (to me) like it has some hope, yet I'm not able to see it.

Note: I'm trying to find a proof with the following constraints:

- No using of vector calculus or multiple integrals
- No using of techniques of infinite sequence and series
- I've just been introduced to improper integrals and hence could only use the direct comparison or limit comparison tests or something elementary like that.

**My Proof**:
Consider
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &= \int_a^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx \\
&= \lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^b\frac{\sin x}{x}dx\\
&= -\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{\cos x}{x}\right]_a^b-\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx \\
&= \frac{\cos a}{a}-\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Now
$$
\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx \leq \lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^b\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{1}{a}
$$
Hence we have
$$
\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx =\frac{1}{a}-h \text{ | }h\geq0
$$
Substituting this result back to $I$, we get
$$
I=\frac{\cos a}{a}-\left[\frac{1}{a}-h\right]=\frac{\cos a-1}{a}+h
$$

Now
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx &= \lim_{a\rightarrow0}\int_a^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx \\
&= \lim_{a\rightarrow0}\frac{\cos a-1}{a}+h \\
&= h
\end{aligned}
$$

This looks neat, but since $h$ is not bound on the other end, I don't see how I could proceed.

Comment: Absolutely integrable implies integrable.

Comment: I would do it this way: $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{b \to  + \infty } \int_a^b {\frac{{\sin x}}{x}dx}  = \frac{{\cos a - 1}}{a} - \mathop {\lim }\limits_{b \to  + \infty } \int_a^b {\frac{{\cos x - 1}}{{x^2 }}dx} .
$$ Can you show that $$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\cos x - 1}}{{x^2 }}dx} 
$$ converges absolutely?

Comment: @CrackedBauxite what does that statement mean?

Comment: Your idea of approaching the tail, from $a$ to $\infty$, using integration by parts is excellent, good job. There is a detail in your $\leq$ step you need to justify, because for now you only have an upper bound, but your left-hand side can be negative.

Comment: This question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67198/does-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxdx-have-an-improper-riemann-integral-or?rq=1 has some more information about this function

Comment: To reconcile the $a \to 0$ part: consider splitting your integral some place and do two improper integrals, one from $0$ to $a$, and one from $a$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Can you use the fact $\frac{\sin x}{x} \leq 1$ for all real $x \neq 0$?

Comment: @Koro I've already proven that the integral is $\leq \frac{1}{a}$

Comment: @Gary where did the $-1$ next to $\cos$ come from?

Comment: @aschepler I don't see how

Comment: @Gary also what does 'converge absolutely' mean?

Comment: Combine my hint with the one from @prets: $\int_0^\infty \frac{sin x}{x} dx = \int_0^1 \frac{sin x}{x} dx + \int_1^\infty \frac{sin x}{x} dx$. Use two different comparison tests to show each part converges.

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa The integral $\int_a^b f(x)dx$ converges absolutely if and only if $\int_a^b |f(x)|dx$ converges. The definition is analogous to absolute convergence of series. Have you learnt about the latter? For the other question: $(\cos x-1)'=\sin x$. I just chose a different function to do the integration by parts. This is because $(\cos x-1)/x^2$ is finite as $x\to 0+$.

Comment: @Gary I haven't learned about this 'absolute convergence' yet. I think I inadvertently ran into this concept. I've made a mistake in trying to apply direct comparison test to prove the convergence of $\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_a^b\frac{\cos x}{x^2}dx$ since the integrand is not positive at certain intervals. So, I've started to see how I can use $\left|\frac{\cos x}{x^2}\right|$ since I can use DCT to this function...in progress.

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa How come you know about DCT but not about absolute convergence? DCT should come much later in one's studies of analysis.

Comment: @Gary I'm studying from 'Thomas Calculus 14the Edition' and that's what I have...

Answer (score 1):

The integral $\int^\infty_0\frac{\sin x}xdx$ converges in the same fashion that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n }n$ converges. This can be seen if we brake the infinte interval $[0,\infty]$ into successive intervals over half periods of the sine function - then the  integrand over each half period roughly decreases as $\frac 1x$ and has alternating sign due to the sine function. This idea can be used to show that the integral converges. Firstly we note that the integral of a continous function ($\sin x/x$ is such at $x=0$ due to removability of the singulatrity) over a finite interval always exist. So we only need to show that the integral $\int_{2\pi}^{m\pi}\frac{\sin x}xdx$ exists as $m\to \infty$ for integers $m$. Indeed:
$$
I(k)=\int_{2\pi}^{2\pi k }\frac{\sin x}xdx=\frac12\bigg\{\int_{2\pi}^{2\pi k }\frac{\sin x}xdx+\int_\pi^{2\pi k-\pi}\frac{\sin (x+\pi)}{x+\pi}dx\bigg\}
$$
where the second term is obtained from the first by change of veariable $x'=x-\pi$. Taking the limit $k\to \infty$ and subtracting and adding finite integrals (over $[2\pi k,2\pi k-\pi]$ and $[2\pi,\pi]$, to the second integral on the right (calling the result now $I_1(k)$) we find:
$$
I_1(\infty)=\frac12\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_{2\pi}^{2\pi k}\sin x\bigg[\frac1x-\frac1{x+\pi}\bigg]dx\le\frac{\pi}2\int_{2\pi}^\infty\frac{dx} {x^2}
$$
and the last integral is known to exist.